# How does PAE work for windows XP? How do i "Install" it?

Tags: pae

I wanted to install XP on a second drive; Mostly to run older games, but im not sure how PAE works.

I wanted originally just to run it on a VirtualMachine but theres AV sync lag and Mouse lag, Im really picky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAE allows 32 bit processors to address memory beyond 4GB limit. This is achieved using 4 additional bits for addressing (32 + 4 bits). With 4 additional bits 16 times more memory can be addressed (2 power 4 = 16) or in total 64GB.

How to set PAE - [Available switch options for the Windows XP and the Windows Server 2003 Boot.ini files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833721)